# Rendering complex components from a loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's super easy to render components from a loop by using `map`.

```js
import Card from './Card';

const Fruits = () => {
  const fruitList = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'];
  return fruitList.map(fruit => <Card fruit={fruit} />)
}
```

What to do when I want to render a bunch of **complex**, **unrelated** components that **cannot be reduced to one generic component**? Below is an example.

```
import Birth from './BirthComponent';
import School from './SchoolComponent';
import Job from './JobComponent';
import Marriage from './MarriageComponent';

const LifeComponent = () => {
  const meaningOfLife = 42; 
  return (
     // How do I use a loop to render these components?
     <React.Fragment>
      <Birth life={meaningOfLife} />
      <School life={meaningOfLife} />
      <Job life={meaningOfLife} />
      <Marriage life={meaningOfLife} />
     </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

In the example above, all the four components are unrelated and differently structured so I cannot make a generic component like in the first example.

Can I do something like `const myLife = [<Birth />, <School />, <Job />, <Marriage />]`. But then, how do I pass props to them?

Comment: I love your naming conventions. But I still don't see why you would want this to be dynamic.

Comment: Would the props be different or all the same?

Comment: I am looking to render them using a loop rather than typing them one below another. The props to each component are always the same.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are returning exactly one JSX element, you can render any collection of components you'd like. Assuming you're OK with them all being rendered next to one another, this would work:

```
import Birth from './BirthComponent';
import School from './SchoolComponent';
import Job from './JobComponent';
import Marriage from './MarriageComponent';

const LifeComponent = () => {
  return (
     // How do I use a loop to render these components?
     <div>
       <Birth />
       <School />
       <Job />
       <Marriage />
     </div>
  )
}
```

**EDIT 2:** If you want to render an actual array of components, I'd recommend creating a higher order component to do the work for you which accepts an array of components as an argument and maps over them.  I made a small example [here](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/MWgrMLL).

You could also just create a fragment or component that renders them all for you.  The thing is you will still need to type the components into the parent component, or into the array, and import them, but it would save some work on adding props, assuming the props are all the same.

Comment: I think he wants something like: ```comps = [Birth, School, Job, Marriage]``` <br/> ```for each comp in comps: render comp```

Comment: That would make sense, the title says loop but he didn't post a loop or even data that can be iterated over so I just made it run, but the same principle applies.

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington, I am not looking to render them as a "group" multiple times. I'm looking to render them at once. The problem is what if there were 1000 more components apart from Birth, School, Job and Marriage.

Comment: Ah, this wasn't clear to me.  I've updated my answer with an example of how you can do that using a higher order component.

Answer (score 0):

If You have components  `App`, `App2`, `App3` and you want to render `App2`,`App3` in `App` you can do something Like this

```
function App(props) {
  const components = [App2,App3];
   const content = components.map((c,k)=>{

           const Newcomponent = c;
           return <Newcomponent key={k} msg="x"/>;

   })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {content}

    </div>
  );
}
```

full code in codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-montalcini-0gqm7)